# Remove part from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this:

```
dir/subdir/file-hash.ext
```

Knowing that the "hash" part in the above text is always 8 numbers/letters long, how can I make this string as shown below:

```
dir/subdir/file.ext
```

The only thing that may change is the string having or not a `/` at the beginning.

I have no idea how can i achieve this

Comment: `.replace(/-\w{8}(?=\.)/, "")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "hash part"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a regular expression :

```
var str2 = str1.replace(/-.{8}\.ext$/, '.ext');
```

If the extension may change (for example `.odt` instead of `.txt` , use

```
var str2 = str1.replace(/-.{8}(\.[\d\w]+)$/, '$1');
```

Comment: You likely intended to escape the `.` before `ext`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed-length you don't need to use a regular expression. Use `(last)indexOf` and `substr`.

```
var path = "dir/subdir/file-01234567.ext"; // or "/dir/subdir/file-01234567.ext"
var pos = path.lastIndexOf("."); // find the last `.`
path = path.substr(0, pos - 8) + path.substr(pos); // dir/subdir/file-.ext
```

If you want it without the trailing `-` use:

```
path = path.substr(0, pos - 9) + path.substr(pos); // dir/subdir/file.ext
```